# function inside for loop in python

Tags: python

how to call function inside for loop with PYTHON

must call this funtion

```
def EE():
    print("dd")
```

inside this

```
def upload_file(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        for f in files:
            filename = fs.save(f.name, f)
            ee=EE()
            print(ee)
            number_of_files=len(files)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            return render(request, 'core/simple_upload.html', {
             # 'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
            })
```

Comment: This is not javascript, white-spaces are meaningful - do not close a bracket on a different line (render...)! Second, the function `EE` doesn't have a return value - what are you expecting to find in `ee` ?

Comment: I do not want return anything. I want to know how to call a function inside for loop. I must iterate that function

Comment: it can be like this

Comment: def printinfo( name, age ):
   "This prints a passed info into this function"
   print "Name: ", name
   print "Age ", age
   return;

Comment: You _do_ call it inside the loop. What exactly is your question?

Comment: it is not working.  is there any way to call a funtion inside a loop. Just like in JAVA

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? I there an error message? If so, please include it in the question.

Comment: "how to call function inside for loop with PYTHON" this is my question

Comment: Your question makes no sense, because you _do_ call the function inside the loop. If you want help, you must explain why do you think the program does not work.

Comment: I spot a `return` in the for-loop. It will exit on the first iteration anyway.

Comment: @Darkonaut Unless the `return` is wrongly indented.

Comment: see da below answer please.  i cant post as comment

Comment: it says "Performing system checks..." and stuck

Comment: this does  not print anything

Comment: You can edit your question, don't post as answer unless it _is_ an answer. Before thinking about putting anything in a for loop, make sure it works for one item of the iterable, in your case for one file. Your `EE` function prints to stdout and returns only `None` and that gets printed out. If you want to assign some return value from `EE` with `ee=EE()` you have to _let_ return `EE` something in the first place by replacing `print` with `return` within `EE`.

Comment: @Darkonaut          thank  a loT

Comment: @DYZ    thank u very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have written is correct. Since your function doesn't returns any value, I doubt whether you will receive the desired output. 
Assuming the function to be called and the other are in the same scope.

```
def sample_function():
    return "This is a sample function."

def main_function():
     # function call
     x = sample_function()
     print(x)
     # add your logic here.
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sentence_finder(text, word):
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    return [sent for sent in sentences if word in word_tokenize(sent)]

def EE(filename,no_of_files):


for i in range(no_of_files):
    try:
        print('\n')
        print(i+1)
        pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
        count = 0
        text = ""
        # The while loop will read each page
        while count < num_pages:
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
            count += 1
            text += pageObj.extractText()

        # This if statement exists to check if the above library returned #words. It's done because PyPDF2 cannot read scanned files.
        if text != "":
            text = text
        # If the above returns as False, we run the OCR library textract to #convert scanned/image based PDF files into text
        else:
            text = textract.process(filename, method='tesseract', language='eng')
        # select relevnt section

        # education qulification

        textt = re.search(r'EDUCATION\n.*?SKILLS', text, re.DOTALL).group()
        edu_qulification = textt[textt.find('\n') + 1:textt.rfind('\n')]

        srt1=edu_qulification.lower()
        # print(edu_qulification)
        str12 = srt1.replace("\n", ". ")
        str2 = str12.replace("m.s.", "master")
        # print(str2)

        syn = synonyms = wordnet.synsets('degree')
        syn_set1 = list(chain.from_iterable([word.lemma_names() for word in synonyms]))

        syn = synonyms = wordnet.synsets('BACHELOR')
        syn_set2 = list(chain.from_iterable([word.lemma_names() for word in synonyms]))

        syn = synonyms = wordnet.synsets('Master')
        syn_set3 = list(chain.from_iterable([word.lemma_names() for word in synonyms]))

        listone = ['bsc','be', 'btech']
        listtwo =['m.s.']

        mergedlist = listone + syn_set1 + syn_set2 + syn_set3 + listtwo
        # print(mergedlist)

        for i in mergedlist:

            sent_part=sentence_finder(str2,i)
            # print(sent_part)
            if not sent_part:
                pass
            else:
                Digree = sentence_finder(str2, i)




        synn = synonyms = wordnet.synsets('university')
        syn_seta = list(chain.from_iterable([word.lemma_names() for word in synonyms]))

        synn = synonyms = wordnet.synsets('institute')
        syn_setb= list(chain.from_iterable([word.lemma_names() for word in synonyms]))

        synn = synonyms = wordnet.synsets('college')
        syn_setc = list(chain.from_iterable([word.lemma_names() for word in synonyms]))

        listthree=['center']
        mergedlistt = listthree + syn_seta + syn_setb + syn_setc
        # print(mergedlistt)
        for j in mergedlistt:

            sent_partt = sentence_finder(str2, j)
            # print(sent_partt)
            if not sent_partt:
                pass
            else:
                University = sentence_finder(str2, j)



        # Digree = sentence_finder(str2, 'BACHELOR')
        # University = sentence_finder(str2, 'UNIVERSITY')


        print(Digree)
        print(University)
        print(".................................................................")
        # print(University)


    except:
        print("No Education Qualification mentioned")
```